# How to add message if data doesn't exist PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have to make PL/SQL block that shows the maximum salary of the employees, by typing in the job_id and departement_id. I already done that, but now if I type in some random number or random name it doesn't do anything. So my point is how can I raise a message if the data that I typed in is wrong or doesn't exist. Here is what I've done so far:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
depid EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE := &Enter_Departement_ID;
jbid EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID%TYPE := '&enter_job_title';
max_sal EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(salary) into max_sal FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=depid and job_id = jbid;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The max salary for department ' || depid || ' and job ' || jbid || ' is ' || max_sal);
END;
```

I assume it should be something simple, but I'm fairly new to this. Thank you in advance for  your time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `If Exists(Your Query)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add something like:

```
IF max_sal IS NOT NULL THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The max salary for department ' || depid || ' and    job ' || jbid || ' is ' || max_sal);
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No entry found');
END IF;`
```